# EDM2 (Encyclopedic Dictionary of Mathematics from Japan Math. Soc.) and updates

Tags: reference-request, paper-request

The Japan Mathematical Society has published their Encyclopedic Dictionary of Mathematics 2nd edition (EDM2) some time ago.

I was wondering if there were a digital version online or any updated versions of this, past the 1993 third printing of that second edition, or any collaborated works to update this specific text.

There are some very well written articles in there.

Comment: I have a hardcopy, given to me as a graduation present. I am not aware of any updates.

Comment: Probably any updated versions would have been listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedic_Dictionary_of_Mathematics). Sometime around 5 to 8 years ago I got a good-as-new copy of the 2-volume 1980 MIT Press paperback edition (with the original box set) at a nearby bookstore for only $15, although given [this amazon page for it](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0262590107), I suppose the price wasn't as much of [a steal](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+steal) as I originally thought.